# skydrive System.Dynamic.DynamicObject

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, onedrive

I'm trying to get a listing of all the folders for a signed in user on SkyDrive.

```
LiveOperationResult operationResult = await client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files");
dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> folderData = (Dictionary<string, object>)result;
List<object> folders = (List<object>)folderData["data"];

foreach (object item in folders)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> folder = (Dictionary<string, object>)item;
    if (folder["name"].ToString() == "Folder Name")
    {
        showToastMessage(folder["id"].ToString());
        return;
    }
}
```

However, on this line:

```
Dictionary<string, object> folderData = (Dictionary<string, object>)result;
```

I'm getting an error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'

Does anyone have any idea how I can do get around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`LiveOperationResult.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/microsoft.live.liveoperationresult.result) isn't necessarily guaranteed to be a `Dictionary<string, object>`. It is however defined as an `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Mind you, you don't appear to even need to cast the `Result` property to a dictionary of any sort; you should be able to use the `dynamic` variable to directly access the list you want to iterate.

```
List<object> folders = (List<object>)result.data;
```

Comment: A note: I'm not sure exactly what SkyDrive's schema is, so you may need to cast that to a different collection class or interface, such as `IEnumerable<object>` instead.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for.  I can't submit it as answered for another 4 minutes!  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you receive this because you have declared `result` using the following code

```
dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
```

this will declare `result` as a new `System.Dynamic.DynamicObject` so that, when we say

```
Dictionary<string, object> folderData = (Dictionary<string, object>)result;
```

You are trying to convert `result` of type `System.Dynamic.DynamicObject` to `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` which is not possible and that's why you receive the error.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: @JeffV No problems at all, I'm glad you had your issue resolved. Have a great day :)